# Converting python file into executable in ubuntu 12.04 OS

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, executable-format

I have developed a python script to automate few things present in text file.
when converted this python file to the executable in ubuntu20.04 version(through pyinstaller) works very well.

The same executable is not working on ubuntu 12.04 OS(an older version Linux). However, the python file(.py) file works without any issues in 12.04 as well

Please do suggest how to convert the python file to the executable in ubuntu 12.04 OS version

python version: 2.7
ubuntu: 12.04 version

Comment: what's the error message ? if you get any

Comment: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 0):

humm, probably execution permission issue.

run this in your terminal:

```
chmod 777 {file path/name}
```

this gives a file , read/write and execute permission to the current user.

also, another possible issue could be that you are compiling your python code for 64-bit system and your old system (ubuntu 12.04) is a 32-bit OS?

to find out , you can run this command :

```
uname -ipm
```

while you are compiling using pyinstaller pass this param :

```
pyinstaller --target-arch=32bit scripts
```

from [pyinstaller doc](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html), you can't make your compiled app on linux forward-compatible:

> The GNU/Linux standard libraries such as glibc are distributed in 64-bit and 32-bit versions, and these are not compatible. As a result you cannot bundle your app on a 32-bit system and run it on a 64-bit installation, nor vice-versa. You must make a unique version of the app for each word-length supported.

Comment: The permission is set with "chmod 777". still the same issue(cannot execute binary file) Ubuntu 12.04 is 32-bit OS

Comment: @Shiva ok then its the 32 bit /64 bit incompatibility , you are compiling your code for 64 bit and it can't be executed on a 32bit OS

Comment: okay. How to compile a python file in 32 bit OS(ubuntu: 12.04 version)?

Comment: @Shiva what tool are you using for compiling? you should be able tio find docs regarding that subject

Comment: Tried installing "pyinstaller" which helps in creating binary executable in 12.04 OS.  Getting below error during installation: "Downloading/unpacking pyinstaller
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyinstaller
No distributions at all found for pyinstaller
Storing complete log in /home/username/.pip/pip.log"

Comment: @Shiva then pass `--target-arch` parameter when you are compiling , see updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244616/discussion-between-shiva-and-eshirvana).